# Choose which Google Account when accessing Google Groups?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account, google-groups

I have a personal *Gmail account*, and a business *Google Apps* account. Throughout the day I am logged into both mail interfaces in my browser (Gmail and Google Apps Mail). With the fairly new feature of being able to log into multiple Google Accounts at the same time, this is an easy task.

Recently, I was added to a *Google Group* for something. The user invited me to the group via my Google Apps email address. Now when I visit the Google Group, it will not allow me to view it, because it thinks I'm trying to access the Group using my Gmail address, which is not the address I was invited to the group with.

The only way I can see the access the group is if I log out of my Gmail account and am only logged in with my *Google Apps* account. Then I can access it just fine.

However, even then, if I log back into my Gmail account and refresh the Group page, it kicks me out again, thinking that I'm again trying to access it using my Gmail account.

So I do I fix this? Is there some way to choose which *Google Account* you want to use when accessing a Google Group?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Google groups now supports multiple sign in. See [Ruben's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76634/4119).

---

*Original Answer*

Google groups does not support multiple sign in. Because of this, it should use whatever account you logged into first in your current browser session. (The one marked as default in the account dropdown in gmail)

If this is not the behavior you are seeing, that would seem to be a bug, since it goes against the information on their official [help topic](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=181602).

Comment: At this time, Google Groups support multiple sign in.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's possible to sign in to multiple accounts and to switch from one to another from the Google bar at many Google services, including Google Groups.

From [Sign in to multiple accounts at once - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en)

If you have more than one Google Account, you can use multiple sign-in to switch between accounts without having to sign out and back in again. For example, if you have one Google Account for personal use and a different Google Account for business, you can easily switch between the two within the same browser (like Chrome or Firefox) using multiple sign-in.

**Add your Google Accounts**
1. Sign in to Google.
2. Click your profile photo or email address at the top-right corner of the page.
3. Click **Add account** from the drop-down menu.
[image: Account information while signed in to one account]

4. Enter the username and password for another account you want to access, and click Sign in.

**Switch between accounts**
1. Click your profile photo or email address at the top right of the page.
2. Choose the account you’d like to sign in to.
[image: Account information while signed in to two accounts.]

Answer (score -1):

You can associated multiple email addresses in a Google Account, which should allow you to "transfer" the invite over to your other address.

Comment: Google Apps email addresses can't be added as alternante address to Gmail accounts and vice versa.