# How do I accept an invitation to Google Groups sent to my other email address?

Tags: google-groups

The information in this question

[Choose which Google Account when accessing Google Groups?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/choose-which-google-account-when-accessing-google-groups)

is no longer current

I am signed into Google and in Gmail click a link to an invitation made to another of my email addresses. I tried adding that email to the Gmail account as an alias, but the Google group in question did not let me in.

**Must** I ask the owner to resend to the Gmail account or can I sync/alias the other address to my Google account? I prefer to not use my main Gmail account for the list in question.

Comment: The referred question is about a different topic as it is about accessing the application instead of an specific group. By the way, [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76634/88163) to the referred question is still current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't yet added your desired email address as an alternate email address to your Google Account, do that first. See [Sign in to your Google Account with another email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en) for details.

Then, go to the group membership settings, and change the email address to be used for that group.

From [My membership settings - Google Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047839?hl=en)

> ## My membership settings
>
> You can use your group membership settings to customize your name and
> email address in a group, whether or not you show your photo and a
> link to your Google profile, and how often you get email from the
> group.
>
> ### Choose your group membership settings.
>
> 1. Go to [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com).
> 2. Near the top left corner, click **My Groups**.
> 3. Find the name of the group > next to your name, click **Edit**.
> 4. Pick your settings using the "Setting options and how to choose them" section of this article.
> 5. In the lower left corner, click **Save**.

Comment: Thanks. Does this have any side effects or can I safely reverse the group email setting after accepting the invitation?

Comment: If the email address that you want to use for the group subscription isn't already linked to a Google account, there are no side effects that I'm aware of them and you can safely reverse the group email settings after accepting the invitation. If you want/need to use a different Google account, you should ask for and invitation for that account.

Comment: Damn, what a process for such a simple thing :) Thank you!